# Compare 2 JSON Lists of elements

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have below 2 json

```
json_1=[{'store_type'='HQ',
           'store_address'='123 Street, B8',
              'store_city'='Houston',
                'store_state'='Texas'},
        {'store_type'='Retail',
          'store_address'='XYZ Road, Avenue',
              'store_city'='Asutin',
                 'store_state'='Texas'}]

json_2=[{'store_type'='HQ',
           'store_address'='777 Street',
             'store_city'='Houston',
                'store_state'='Texas'}]
```

I need to compare the json_1 with json_2, and in this case if any difference I need to update some downstream systems with data from json_1

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: compare and if any difference just flag it. json_1 would be final expected result in case of any change

Comment: Without an ID column this could be a pretty difficult task. Are there any guarantees about order eg. the first object will always be first, second always second...?